# Image Sprites looks choppy/jerky

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to animate image to canvas.

in the html file I have dog.png and it's an Image Sprites.

```
<img id="dog" src="images/dog.png" alt="dog" />
```

in CSS file:

```
#dog{
    object-position: 0 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

In the javascript there's a function with:

```
$("#dog").css("object-position",(incrementNum*-60) +"px 0");
```

where incrementNum start with 0.

The problem is that the image animation turn out choppy/jerky.

How do I make the images looks good?
Thank you

Comment: Can you create a demo (or) atleast upload your sprite online and give us the URL.While I do understand your question, it would be easier to work with your own image than something else.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just realize that the documentGetElementById take the whole sprite image and doesn't apply the css. That's why the choppy image was actually a long image that was squeezed into 50 x 50px